# How to add feature extractor netwrok for example mobilenetv2 to tensorflow's object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

[This tutorial](http://%20https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) discusses how to use objection detection API at tensorflow.
I am looking for the tutorial explaining how to add feature extractor such as mobilenetV2 to tensorflow's object detection framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the Tensorflow provided Model Zoo? :)

It includes various object detection models with various feature extractors such as MobileNet, Inception, ResNet etc.

Here below you will find a link to the Tensorflow Detection Model Zoo, where you can choose detection model architectures, Region-Based (R-CNN) or Single Shot Detector (SSD) models, and feature extractors.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

You can download a frozen graph of the pre-trained models based on COCO, Kitti and Open-Images etc.

Comment: It doesn't have FasterRCNN for MobileNetV2

Comment: Any reason for that combination? Usually SSD and MobileNet are combined, because they both focus on real-time application, as they are both state of the art when it comes to the accuracy/speed trade off.

Comment: SSD is not good for accuracy. FasterRCNN is better, but I like to increase the speed as fast as possible. My applications is like signboard text reading. Sometimes the image has only text like DOAR. The whole image has only DOAR and image size is about 75 x 150 size. Then when I apply SSD, I don't get correct reading. I applied SSD MobileNet V1 FPN. That 75x150 image is resized to 650 x 650 in training and inference. I don't understand why I can't read using SSD, but FasterRCNN is ok. Any idea? I trained DORA with one ground trouth for one alphabet.

Comment: I can not tell without seeing your data, however for your original question of creating a new model.

This might be of help to you: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/defining_your_own_model.md

Comment: Thanks that is the one I am looking for.

Comment: I suspect my inference doesn't work well is because of network length. If network length is too long, sometimes the feature is not doing good. I'll test making shorter network length.